# Problems with Mailkit IMAP - Authentication with string is not possible

Tags: imap, mailkit, mimekit

I have a strange problem with my IMAP authentication here.
I cannot authenticate if I´m trying to use string variables. I really need to type in my account and my password which does really make no sense to me.

THIS DOES NOT WORK!

```
    using (var client = new ImapClient(new ProtocolLogger("imap.log")))
        {

            using (var cancel = new CancellationTokenSource())
            {
                //LogIn
                client.Connect("imap.gmail.com", 993, MailKit.Security.SecureSocketOptions.SslOnConnect);
                var credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
                client.Authenticate(credentials, cancel.Token);


                var personal = client.GetFolder(client.PersonalNamespaces[0]);
                f1.tbl_folderTableAdapter1.Insert(ID, PARENTID, username);

                client.Disconnect(true);
            }
        }
```

BUT THIS WORK

```
  using (var client = new ImapClient(new ProtocolLogger("imap.log")))
        {

            using (var cancel = new CancellationTokenSource())
            {
                //LogIn
                client.Connect("imap.gmail.com", 993, MailKit.Security.SecureSocketOptions.SslOnConnect);
                client.Authenticate("funnyemailhere", "anothernicepasswordhere");


                var personal = client.GetFolder(client.PersonalNamespaces[0]);
                f1.tbl_folderTableAdapter1.Insert(ID, PARENTID, username);

                client.Disconnect(true);
            }
        }
```

Can you see any problems here ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: The authentication is in a constructor which is in a class. The constructor receive its information from a button_clickevent.

Comment: he only way this could possibly not work is if your string variables have the wrong values.